# Folders on Asus NAS share created by Windows client not accessible from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, samba

I've seen a lot of such issues related to Samba however my issue is the share is on an Asus router so I don;t have a lot of options for changing settings.

Asus router with Samba share.
Connection security is with Samba account that all users on the network have.

All clients (windows/linux) can connect to and see the contents of the share.

Folders created by Windows clients can be seen by Linux clients but NOT the contents.

The error is:

```
ls: reading directory '.': Device or resource busy
```

Looking at the folder permission via windows reveals that "everyone" has "full" access.

I have remote ssh'd into the router and can see that all files/folders have the same linux level ownerships and permissions Admin/root rwxrwxrwx. Including those created by the windows clients.

That leaves the samba setup which I hesitant to play around with.

What do I have to do in order to give access to the Linux clients?

Just as I was writing this I found a work around.

Just shutdown the windows client!!!  Really in this day and age.

It appears the windows client is holding open some samba resource that prohibits other clients from accessing the files in the folder.